# How to map columns values on change to column 1 values in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, handsontable

```
     {singlegroupcommisions && singlegroupcommisions.length ? <HotTable data={singlegroupcommisions} colHeaders={['Commission In % For CA','Commission In % For CR','Subcripiton Plan Id', 'Plan Name']}  colWidths= {[150, 200, 250, 150]}/> : "Loading..."}
```

In state I am declaring settings on change

```
  settings: {


            colHeaders:[' Plan name', 'Commission In % For CA','Commission In % For CR', ],
            data: [{subscription_plan_name:"", comission_for_ca:"", commission_for_cr: "" }],


           columns: [

                { data:"subscription_plan_name"},
                { data: "commission_for_ca"},
                { data: "commission_for_cr"},


            ],

            minSpareRows: 0,
            contextMenu: true,
            rowHeaders:true, 
            manualColumnResize: true,
            columnSorting: true, 
            manualRowResize: true, 
            manualRowMove: true,   
            manualColumnMove: true, 
            colWidths: [150, 170, 170],


          },
```

I am able to populate all the plans name on change values how i need to map to particular row name:

[image]

I am using react handsontable how i can map the column 2 and column 3 on change values to particular row data